# How to control transaction in the function

Tags: postgresql, function, transactions

I am calling the test functions through wrappertest.psql file.
wrappertest.psql

```
select paymentfailedtest();       
select paymentsuccesstest();
```

Test functions are placed in the testfunctions.psql file.

Comment: Hi Ram What data do you need to ROLLBACK; and what data do you need to COMMIT;

Comment: This question seems similar, does this help ?https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/145785/94886

Answer (score 0):

In Postgresql, Functions does not allow to rollback/commit transaction. You need to use stored procedure avail the functionality of rollback & commit.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE transaction_test1()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 0..9 LOOP
        INSERT INTO test1 (a) VALUES (i);
        IF i % 2 = 0 THEN
            COMMIT;
        ELSE
            ROLLBACK;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END
$$;

CALL transaction_test1();
```

refer https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-transactions.html for more info.

Comment: I have edited my post what data needs to be committed and what needs to rollbacked. Thank you

Comment: Hi 
As you suggested I have took the update statements out from the function paymentsuccesstest 
and created the procedure and called in the testfunctions.psql along with other functions.
Getting error invalid transaction termination.

CREATE or replace PROCEDURE transaction_test1()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
update invoice set inv_tot = 9000 where customer_no = 'CUST5566';
update invoicepaid set inv_paid = 6000 where customer_no = 'CUST5566';
commit;
    END
$$;

CALL transaction_test1();

please help me.

Comment: can you please update your question? it is hard to read/understand. I would recommend narrowing down to a simple scenario and make it work.

Comment: Postgresql does not support nested transactions. Functions internally manage transactions. when you call function>sp there is nesting in a transaction. to solve this you need to put all the logic in one stored procedure and use rollback & commit appropriately.

Comment: Can you please provide an example. It would be great help for me.